# Joint p.d.f $Y=x_1/x_2$ for two independent continuous random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The question reads like this: 
Two independent continuous random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a joint p.d.f $f(x_1,x_2)$. Determine the p.d.f of $Y=X_2/X_1$, assuming $Y>0$. (That is $Y$ is greater than zero.)

I would realy appreciate it if someone could please assist me.

Comment: Wellcome to here

Comment: Thank you! Although I hope I have been able to use the tags properly.

Comment: Which method would you like to use? Do you know of transforming the density via Jacobians?

Comment: I think I do. Could you please elaborate further if you do not mind?

Comment: Could I find G(Y) and then differentiate to find the p.d.f of Y. But I am stuck on the integrating of this i.e. find the limits. Are the limits for x1 0 to infinity and the limit of y from xz to infinity?

Comment: @ArchimedesGirl, sure I can elaborate, maybe later tonight. But can you maybe edit your original post and include your approach, your thoughts and your difficulties? I'm sure it'll help others to know where you're stuck. Remember to use dollar signs around math.